# Laminas Unable to resolve service "Laminas\Authentication\AuthenticationService" to a factory

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework3, laminas

I'm learning Laminas Framework for PHP and expanding the features of the Album tutorial provided in the official documentation. I've successfully added features like login and registration to the Album page. Recently, I've started integrating Doctrine for database storage and object mapping.

Prior to incorporating Doctrine, everything was functioning smoothly. However, I encountered issues related to the "laminas\di" package in my Composer dependencies, which caused storage problems with Doctrine. The error message I received was:

**DoctrineModule\Cache\LaminasStorageCache" could not be created. Reason: Could not resolve value for parameter "storage" of type Laminas\Cache\Storage\StorageInterface in class DoctrineModule\Cache\LaminasStorageCache (requested as DoctrineModule\Cache\LaminasStorageCache).**

Any insights or guidance on how to resolve this "Laminas\Authentication\AuthenticationService" error would be greatly appreciated.

To resolve this issue, I decided to remove the "laminas/laminas-di" package from my Composer dependencies. While this resolved the storage issue with Doctrine, I now face a new error message:

**Unable to resolve service "Laminas\Authentication\AuthenticationService" to a factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration?**

It's worth noting that I don't have any explicit dependencies on "laminas/laminas-di" in my project since I removed it via Composer, which is why the error related to "laminas\di" is puzzling.
this is my module.config.php if it may help

```
return [
    'Laminas\Cache',
    'Laminas\Mvc\Plugin\FlashMessenger',
    'Laminas\Paginator',
    'Laminas\Session',
    'Laminas\Navigation',
    'Laminas\Form',
    'Laminas\I18n',
    'Laminas\InputFilter',
    'Laminas\Filter',
    'Laminas\Hydrator',
    'Laminas\Db',
    'Laminas\Router',
    'Laminas\Validator',
    'Laminas\Diactoros',
    'DoctrineModule',
    'Laminas\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Filesystem',
    'Laminas\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Memory',
    'DoctrineORMModule',
    'Application',
    'Us',
    'Album',
    'Blog',
];
```

Answer (score 1):

As laminas-di was registered as a module in the application there was some kind of auto-wiring active via the an abstract factory, which took place as i didn't defined a factory for it. Whats weired is that lamians\di was already there in my project when i don't recall calling it.
In short I only had to add a factory to my Laminas\Authentication\AuthinticationService which simplified looks like this:

```
    'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        AuthenticationService::class => function ($container) {
            $authService = new AuthenticationService();
            return $authService;
        },
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

The laminas skeleton installer prompts you to add laminas-di during the setup. You may have selected yes. I would also add an alias pointing the AuthenticationServiceInterface to your service. In laminas components, nearly all of the default auto detection of other components that can consume the Authentication service will be looking for the Interface mapping.

Another tip I will pass along is this. Go ahead and provide factories for a custom session container and manager. The reason is that the authentication service will create a default, but so do other components. An example is the captcha, csrf,identity controller plugin and flash messenger. If you provide factories and do not depend on the default implementations then it will unify your session container usage.